# Как на всех мобильниках отключить свойство autoplay?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Пробовал через .trigger отключать при проверке на разрешение <768px, но всё равно не хочет работать почему то  (.owl-car-first и .owl-car-second) это слайдеры-owl.

```js
var owlfirst = $(".owl-car-first");
var owlsec = $(".owl-car-second");

$(owlfirst).owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 0,
  items: 1,

  nav: true,
  dots: false,

  smartSpeed: 700,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 7000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  navText: ["<img src='img/prev_arrow.png'>", "<img src='img/next_arrow.png'>"]
});
```

```
var owlfirst = $(".owl-car-first");
var owlsec = $(".owl-car-second");
if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
  console.log("stop");
  $(owlsec).trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
  $(owlfirst).trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
} else {
  console.log("play");
  $(owlsec).trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
  $(owlfirst).trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
}
});
```

Comment: `$(".owl-car-first")` - из вашего кода без html не понятно - это первый слайдер или первый слайд?

Comment: Может стоит на мобилках вообще не выводить слайдер? Можно заюзать вот эту [либу](https://github.com/matthewhudson/current-device)

Comment: а можно я свой конфиг напишу ??Потому что в вашем не разобратсья

Comment: да конечно можете описать свой конфиг ну у меня обычный конфиг сейчас прикреплю

Comment: Еще бы отмечали правильные ответы - было бы вообще здорово

Answer (score 1):

Прошу, все работает - вот вам мой пример, так как я не вижу вашего кода, пришлось написать свой конфиг а так же выдернуть из примера своего. Переменную взял вашу, так как в моем случае данный конфиг был не нужен.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
 autoplay: true,
 smartSpeed: 800,
 navText: [$('.am-prev'), $('.am-next')],
 autoWidth: false,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
  1000:{
   items: 1
  }
    }
})
$(document).ready(function(){
 var owlfirst = $(".owl-carousel");
     if($(window).width() <= 768) {
   console.log("stop");
   $(owlfirst).trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
     }

  else{
    console.log("play");
    $(owlfirst).trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
  }
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel{
 position: relative;
}
.owl-carousel .item{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200);
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 
}

.owl-carousel .am-next{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: rgba(124, 58, 22, 0.6);
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding-right: 5px;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 50px;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
<button class="am-next"><img src="icons/slider-arrow.svg" alt="next"></button>
    
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```